# How to create a 1px height div in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, height

I have the following code to create a 1px height line:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:1px; background-color:#ff3300; margin-top: -1px;"></div> <!-- top red line -->
```

The code works fine in Firefox, however in IE8, it is displayed as a 10px height line or so. How can I force IE to take into account the specified height?

**Edit:**

- I just tried setting the `min-height` property to 1px but that didn't work either.
- `max-height` is ignored by IE too
- Setting the `line-height` to 1 doesn't help

Why is IE ignoring all my CSS rules?

Comment: Make sure you reset your CSS properly, to disallow any unexpected paddings.

Comment: `div` has no special styling by default. The concept of CSS resets, while recommended practice by many, is a crock.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a line of some sort. Why don't you just use `border-top:#ff3300 solid 1px;` on the element below instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set font-size to 1px; IE is limiting height of this div to font size.

Answer (score 1):

*@Laurent*, if you are still unable to get the desired 1px div, despite of using 
`height:1px; line-height:1px;` font: normal 1px/1px arial; you might require to check your DTD (Document Type Definition) at the top of your webpage code. You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `line-height` *and* `font-size` to 1px.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell without the context... aside from resetting the padding to 0 it could have to do with other elements (probably above). Especially if they're floated. May also try clear:both; Also make sure it doesn't have display:inline; anywhere... It's block by default, and should be block.

It's really poking in the dark without the context.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: This is browser scroll bar problem.
Just you put
body{ margin:0; padding:0;} you can't see line in all browser.

IE7 scroll bar top arrow putting down that line.